# función en JavaScript que reciba un arreglo de números como parámetro

Tags: javascript

de antemano gracias por la colaboracion, como puedo hacer una función en JavaScript que reciba un arreglo de números como parámetro y retorne un nuevo arreglo con los números filtrados?
Es un ejercicio pero no idea de como hacerlo.

El ejemplo del ejercicio es asi:

```
filter([2, 13, 40, 9]); // retorna [13, 40]
```

en realidad no he logrado hacerlo como funcion, pude hacerlo asi:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 30, 40, 50, 60] var numFiltered = [] for (var 
    i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { if(numbers[i] > 10) { numFiltered[i] = 
    numbers[i] } } document.write(numFiltered)
```

pero no es lo que pide el ejercicio

Lo hice ahora asi, pero no muestra los numeros, me muestra en ese ejemplo false true true false es decir q la funcion esta correcta y se esta ejecutando.

```js
var x = [8, 12, 14, 6];
miFuncion(x);

function miFuncion(params) {
  for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    document.write((params[i]>10))
  }
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto disculpen las molestias.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte debes al menos hacer el intento de dicho ejercicio, una vez que estés atorado nos muestras el error y con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: Mauricio, por favor añade tu código a la pregunta. Dale clic a _"editar"_ para hacerlo. Un saludo.

Comment: El filtro que deseas... es de números mayores a 10?

Comment: Si mayores a 10

Comment: Listo amigo, edité mi respuesta. Haz la prueba con el ejemplo que anexé. En caso de que te haya servido la respuesta te agradecería que la marcaras como correcta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes hacer nada *especial*, javascript soporta directamente pasar un arreglo como parámetro, creo que me explico mucho mejor con un ejemplo:

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; 
miFuncion(x);

function miFuncion(params) {
  for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    alert(params[i])
  }
}
```

Dentro de miFuncion ya haces lo que tengas que hacer para filtrar y retornas el arreglo resultante ya filtrado.

## Edición:

Ahora que la pregunta ha *evolucionado* y se entiende claramente la manera de filtrar, voy a mostrarte la manera de hacerlo, incluyendo el retorno del array, que no se había incluido hasta ahora.

```js
var x = [8, 12, 14, 6];
var y = filtrar(x);
console.log(y);

function filtrar(params) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    if (params[i]>10) {
      resultado.push(params[i]);
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Perdon, no retorna numeros, retorna booleanos. He editado la pregunta agregando el codigo como me sugeriste. Disculpa la molestia

Comment: Ok, ya veo la edición de tu pregunta. No retorna, pero imprime booleanos, porque el resultado de la comparación es un booleano. Tu envías a imprimir el resultado de la comparación: `params[i]>10`. Eso va a devolver `true` o `false`.

Comment: @Mauricio, edité mi respuesta para mostrar la solución de acuerdo a la pregunta actual.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude gracias a tu ejemplo.

Comment: Me alegra @Mauricio, ahora, lo mejor es que entiendas bien como funciona. Esto se logra mejor si no copias y pegas el código, sino que lo analizas, lo entiendes y llegas al punto de poder escribirlo por ti mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Como se te menciona, `Javascript` soporta un arreglo como parámetro. Te dejo una función de ejemplo con comentarios para que comprendas un poco más, en este caso obtengo todos los números mayores a 10 en un nuevo `array`:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 30, 40, 50, 60];
var newArray = []; //Este será nuestro nuevo array

//Se crea función que admita un parámetro, en este caso será un array
function generateArray(filters){
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    //Validamos que el valor actual del array es mayor que 10
    if(numbers[i] > 10) { 
    
      //Si es mayor que 10 entonces damos un push al nuevo array
      newArray.push(numbers[i]);   
   }
  }
}

//Mandamos a llamar a nuestra función y le pasamos como parámetro el array "numbers"
generateArray(numbers);

//Imprimimos nuestro nuevo array para validar
console.log(newArray);
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboracion!

Comment: De nada, suerte compañero. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

tu ejercicio esta bien encaminado

```
//creas la variable

var x = [8, 12, 14, 6];

//la función debe devolver un array, por lo que tomo el array devuelto y lo guardo en y)

var y = miFuncion(x);

function miFuncion(params) {

   //creo mi array resultante (solo lo inicializo)  

   var nuevoArray= new Array();

   // creo un índice para este array

   var j = 0;

  for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {

    //pregunto si el numero en el índice "i" es > a 10

    if (params[i] > 10) {

       //asigno el params sub i al nuevo array con subíndice j

       nuevoArray[j] = params[i];

       //corro el índice j uno mas adelante (podría usar la longitud de "nuevoArray"en vez del j)

       j = j + 1;

               }
   }

     // devuelvo el array

      return nuevoArray;
}
```